React useState and useMemo not preserving state during client-side routing
I'm encountering an issue with preserving state in a React component when client-side routing occurs. Specifically, I'm using the useState and useMemo hooks to manage and memoize the state of sorted questions in my application. However, whenever client-side routing happens, the content of the sorted questions changes unexpectedly.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import QuestionCard from "../components/ui/question-card";
import { QnaTypes, qna } from "../lib/qna";
import { getRandomSort } from "../lib/random";

export default function Home() {
  const [sortedQuestions, setSortedQuestions] = useState<QnaTypes[]>([]);

  useMemo(() => {
    const sortedQna = qna.slice(0, 15).sort(getRandomSort);
    setSortedQuestions(sortedQna);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      <h1 className="g-text font-extrabold text-3xl text-center pb-6">Explore questions to practice</h1>
      <div className="flex justify-between flex-wrap items-start gap-3">
        {sortedQuestions.map((question) => (
          <QuestionCard question={question.question} answer={question.answer} id={question.id} key={question.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

In this code, I'm using useState to manage the state of the sorted questions and useMemo to memoize the sorted questions array. Despite this, when client-side routing occurs, the content of sortedQuestions changes.
Could anyone offer guidance on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the state of sorted questions is preserved during client-side routing? Thank you!

I recommend you to have a read about useMemo from the official doc first.
https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo

"the content of sortedQuestions changes" - where? Does it change in the Home component (i.e. if you console.log(sortedQuestions) in this component does it log different results)? Where's the routing?

You really shouldn't call setSortedQuestions from the useMemo callback; and you shouldn't use useMemo at all if you're not going to compute a memoised value that you return. If you meant to initialise the state once, do that by passing an initialiser to useState!
